# DIVIDE using totals in Power BI – Cost per FTE

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image: FTE Table]

I have two columns of data, `FTE REGION TOTAL AMOUNT` and `FTE REGION TOTAL FTE`.

I want to calculate the cost per `FTE` by `Region` (by dividing the sum of the `ActualExpensebyRegion` column by the `ActualFTEbyRegion` column).

My divide formula below is not working

```
costperfte = DIVIDE(fteregiontotal[AMOUNT],fteregiontotal[FTE])
```

I know that Power BI will calculate the sum of each column, but how do I perform a calculation using those sums and divide by region.

Expected Outcome

```
Region                  Cost per FTE
------------------------------------
EMEA                       7,049 
APAC                       2,178 
LATAM                      403,380 
CAM                        1,190 
NALA                       23,797
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this measure:

```
Cost Per FTE by Region := 
VAR Numerator = SUM('fteregiontotal'[Amount])
VAR Denominator = SUM('fteregiontotal'[FTE])
RETURN 
CALCULATE(DIVIDE(Numerator , Denominator ))
```

And use it in a matrix or table with your [Region] in the "Rows" field and the measure in the "Values" field.

Comment: Great! Can you accept my answer as a solution please :)

Comment: Worked a charm indeed